# Access menu links from a module

Tags: routes, 8, entities

I'm trying to display a menu in my module. I've used `\Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('menu')->load('oz-topbar-menu');` which allows me to get the title of the menu, the description, etc.

I obviously need the links of that menu, and I can't understand how to retrieve. From what I've read in the documentation I should probably use [MenuLinkTreeInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21MenuLinkTreeInterface.php/interface/MenuLinkTreeInterface/8) but I don't understand how to instantiate it.

I've tried `\Drupal::menuTree()->load('oz-topbar-menu', $menu_parameters);`. With basic menu parameters it returns a humongous amount of information; I'm guessing it must be the entire menu tree of Drupal.

I tried playing with the parameters of `MenuTreeParameters` (`setTopLevelOnly`, `setRoot('oz-topbar-menu')`) but it returns an empty array.

I've tried sending this as a `MenuTreeParameters` object with `\Drupal::menuTree()->getCurrentRouteMenuTreeParameters('oz-topbar-menu')`, but I still get a massive link tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably just missing the `build()` call.

```
$menu_name = 'my-custom-menu';
$menu_parameters = \Drupal::menuTree()->getCurrentRouteMenuTreeParameters($menu_name);
$tree = \Drupal::menuTree()->load($menu_name, $menu_parameters);
$renderable = \Drupal::menuTree()->build($tree);
print \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($renderable);
```

Core is the best example for these kinds of things. I pulled the above from [`SystemMenuBlock::build()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21src%21Plugin%21Block%21SystemMenuBlock.php/function/SystemMenuBlock%3A%3Abuild/8).

Comment: Alright, I'll try that tomorrow morning. Thank you!

Comment: Beautiful, that did the trick.